# GUI to text file conversion

Tags: user-interface, text-files

I am new to programming and am trying to understand how to get inputs from a GUI converted into a text file. Sorry for the vague question, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed too vague question for SO. Why don't you try it yourself? That's the only way to understand.

Comment: Which language are you trying to use>